# Working with both strings and substrings

Tags: julia

Given that:

```
julia> SubString <: String
false
```

How would you write a function that accepts both substrings and strings?

```
julia> function myfunction(ss::String)
           @show ss, typeof(ss)
       end
myfunction (generic function with 1 method)

julia> myfunction("Hello World")
(ss, typeof(ss)) = ("Hello World", String)
("Hello World", String)

julia> s = split("Hello World")
2-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "Hello"
 "World"

julia> foreach(x -> myfunction(x), s)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching myfunction(::SubString{String})
Closest candidates are:
  myfunction(::String) at REPL[11]:2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two ways you can do this:

1. Use `AbstractString` rather than `String` in the function definition;
2. Define the function twice, once for `String` and once for `SubString`, which will generate `myfunction (generic function with 2 methods)`.

The point is that `SubString` is a subtype of `AbstractString`, not `String`. You can see this by entering `supertype(SubString)`.

Comment: My experience is the following: 1) use `AbstractString` as per Mark's recommendation. This should cover at least 99% of your needs and you can use other string implementations e.g. from Strs.jl. 2) There is a slight chance that you might rely on the fact that you receive `String` or `SubString{String}` (e.g. you want to use specific memory layout of `String`); then I would recommend to use `Union{String, SubString{String}}` signature. In general specifying type signature as `SubString` is of very little use as `SubString` is not a concrete type (as opposed to e.g. `SubString{String}`).